# Angle of Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface, smooth

I'm trying to smoothen a curve on the mesh I'm editing.
Using the subsurf modifier this gets the job somewhat done, although it alters the angle of the curve and isn't using the angle that I'd like to.
Is there any way to get the angle that I drew in red with this or a different modifier?
(Highlighted is the subsurf, behind that the old mesh)

[image: Subsurf]